# Laravel application hosted on GCP k8s has stopped logging errors into Cloud Logging correctly

Tags: php, laravel, kubernetes, google-cloud-logging, monolog

My Laravel application hosted on GCP k8s has stopped logging errors into Cloud Logging correctly. I haven't intentionally changed anything.

I'm just using the config

```
  env:
  - name: LOG_CHANNEL
    value: stderr
  - name: LOG_LEVEL
    value: debug
  - name: LOG_STDERR_FORMATTER
    value: '\Monolog\Formatter\GoogleCloudLoggingFormatter::class'
```

And its resulting in the error below

```
   [2023-06-06 22:05:37] laravel.EMERGENCY: Unable to create configured logger. Using emergency logger. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Contracts\\Container\\BindingResolutionException(code: 0): Target class [\\Monolog\\Formatter\\GoogleCloudLoggingFormatter::class] does not exist. at /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:891)
    [stacktrace]
    #0 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(770): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('\\\\Monolog\\\\Format...')
    #1 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(856): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('\\\\Monolog\\\\Format...', Array, true)
    #2 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(706): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolve('\\\\Monolog\\\\Format...', Array)
    #3 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(841): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('\\\\Monolog\\\\Format...', Array)
    #4 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(439): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make('\\\\Monolog\\\\Format...', Array)
    #5 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(394): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->prepareHandler(Object(Monolog\\Handler\\StreamHandler), Array)
    #6 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(220): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->createMonologDriver(Array)
    #7 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(135): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->resolve('stderr', Array)
    #8 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(122): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->get('stderr')
    #9 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(645): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->driver()
    #10 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(274): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->error('Undefined varia...', Array)
    #11 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(49): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->report(Object(ErrorException))
    #12 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(143): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->handleException(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(ErrorException))
    #13 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #14 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #15 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #16 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #17 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(121): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #18 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handleStatefulRequest(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Session\\Store), Object(Closure))
    #19 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #20 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #21 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #22 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(67): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #23 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #24 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #25 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(799): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
    #26 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(776): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #27 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(740): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
    #28 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(729): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #29 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(190): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #30 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #31 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #32 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #33 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #34 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #35 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #36 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #37 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #38 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #39 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #40 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #41 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/HandleCors.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #42 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\HandleCors->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #43 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php(39): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #44 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #45 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #46 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(165): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
    #47 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(134): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #48 /var/www/html/public/index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #49 {main}
    
    [previous exception] [object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class \"\\Monolog\\Formatter\\GoogleCloudLoggingFormatter::class\" does not exist at /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:889)
    [stacktrace]
    #0 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(889): ReflectionClass->__construct('\\\\Monolog\\\\Format...')
    #1 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(770): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('\\\\Monolog\\\\Format...')
    #2 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(856): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('\\\\Monolog\\\\Format...', Array, true)
    #3 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(706): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolve('\\\\Monolog\\\\Format...', Array)
    #4 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(841): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('\\\\Monolog\\\\Format...', Array)
    #5 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(439): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make('\\\\Monolog\\\\Format...', Array)
    #6 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(394): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->prepareHandler(Object(Monolog\\Handler\\StreamHandler), Array)
    #7 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(220): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->createMonologDriver(Array)
    #8 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(135): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->resolve('stderr', Array)
    #9 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(122): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->get('stderr')
    #10 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(645): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->driver()
    #11 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(274): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->error('Undefined varia...', Array)
    #12 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(49): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->report(Object(ErrorException))
    #13 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(143): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->handleException(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(ErrorException))
    #14 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #15 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #16 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #17 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #18 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(121): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #19 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handleStatefulRequest(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Session\\Store), Object(Closure))
    #20 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #21 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #22 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #23 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(67): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #24 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #25 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #26 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(799): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
    #27 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(776): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #28 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(740): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
    #29 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(729): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #30 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(190): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #31 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #32 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #33 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #34 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #35 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #36 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #37 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #38 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #39 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #40 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #41 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #42 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/HandleCors.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #43 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\HandleCors->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #44 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php(39): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #45 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #46 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #47 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(165): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
    #48 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(134): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #49 /var/www/html/public/index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #50 {main}
```

When I shell into the container I can see the file exists and all other parts of the application are behaving as expected.

[image]

Comment: Can you share any reproducible steps or docs you are following for configuring these logs..